# How to check the .Text property of the sender object in my event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, event-handling

```
private void NuestroButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if //the sender's .Text/.Content is X
       {
            //Do something
            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Alert("Hello World");
       }

   }
```

How can I use something like sender.Text to see what the .Text is of the clicked button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the pseudo code below:

```
private void NuestroButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button foo = sender as Button; // Cast to the type we're expecting it to be

   if( foo != null && foo.Content == "X" )
   {
        //Do something
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Alert("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: Just one remark : in Silverlight, Button doesn't have a Text property, it has a Content property instead (because the content can be anything, not just text)

Comment: Now less pseudo, more code (I was also missing the brackets from the if - the cast if the important bit, of course...